# dns how to assign ip to ubuntu domains

Tags: networking, command-line, server, dns

I have a dns. I set it up, connected 2 domains to ns, now I need to assign IP to these domains via dns. You can see that the domain is connected to ns through the command:

```
 ~$ dig +noall +authority +answer ns csgo.sbs. @a.nic.sbs.
 csgo.sbs. 3600 IN NS ns1.makeuppro.shop.
 csgo.sbs. 3600 IN NS ns2.makeuppro.shop.
```

Now I need to register domains in the DNS and which IP they will look at. I did not find information on the Internet how to do this. The `nslookup csgo.sbs` command prints `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Comment: Go to makeuppro.shop and add an A entry for . (Dot means the start of the domain) and point it to your IP address. The place where you host your domain should provide you instructions or a website in how to do that